# How to group by Year and Month?

Tags: c#, linq

I have DataTable with 2 columns: Id(long), Date(DataTime).
How to group this to get grouped list in linq:

```
2017.08.03
      345675
      877685
2017.08.04
      988798
      898967
      675675
```

Next, I must to send each of group to stored procedure as a parameter.
I can have about 300000 rows at data table so linq extension should be fast.

Ok. Now, I want to do something foreach groups. How Can I do it?

```
var GroupedbyDates = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => ((DateTime)x["Date"]).Date);

 for (var i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
 {
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomething);
                tasks.Add(task);
 }

private DoSomething()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var item = ?? //one of groups;

         if (item != null)
         {
            var result = DoSomething2();
            HandleResult(result);
         }             
    }
}
```

How to iterate on IGrouped??

UPDATE

I have something like this:

```
var r = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => ((DateTime)x["Date"]).Year) 
    .ToDictionary(year => year.Key, g => g.GroupBy(x =>  
      ((DateTime)x["Date"]).Month)                                   
    .ToDictionary(month => month.Key,  d => d
    .Select(t => new { Root_Id = t["Id"] })));
```

to:

```
2017.08.03
      345675
      877685
2017.08.04
      988798
      898967
      675675
```

Comment: any effort from your side to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var grouped = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x = > new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month });
```

Comment: Thanks big dawg that helped. I figured you could group by Year & Month but I didn't know how to express it. I still forget about that "new {   }" thing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example in the question to get groups by **date**

```
2017.08.03  
    345675  
    877685  
2017.08.04
    988798  
    898967  
    675675
```

You can use `DateTime.Date` property to remove time part and group items by pure date

```
var groups = datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(item => item.Date.Date);
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this solution?
Don't forget to use AsParallel() to make this LINQ more effective on big data.

```
// dt - your DataTable with DataRows, where dataRow[0] - is int id, and dataRow[1] - is DateTime.
dt.Rows.AsParallel()
                .ConvertAll(dr => new
                {
                    id = int.Parse((dr as DataRow)[0].ToString()),
                    dateTime = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Parse((dr as DataRow)[1].ToString()).Ticks),
                })
                .GroupBy(objIdDate => objIdDate.dateTime.TotalDays);
```